# Replace by area on Matlab

Tags: matlab

I have a question about how can I find and replace some values by area. I have three matrixs. It has the same length = 1700*1700. The third matrix, called 'mask' has two different values= 0 and 255.

```
a
b
mask
```

I want to find all the same values that are on the "0 area" (0 area defined on the mask) on the "a" matrix, and replace with the b values on the "a" matrix. Is that possible? So for example, on this simple example, this is what I want to get:

```
a= (3 4 2 5)
b = (2 4 5 7)
mask= (255 255 0 255)
```

Result=

```
c= 3 4 5 5
```

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Another way to do it using logical indexing.

```
>> a= [3 4 2 5];
>> b = [2 4 5 7];
>> mask= [255 255 0 255];
>> c = b;
>> logicalMask = mask>0;
>> c(logicalMask) = a(logicalMask) % Set values from a where mask>0

c =

   3     4     5     5
```

Answer (score 3):

Convert your mask to a logical matrix:

```
mask = mask > 0
```

And then go ahead and multiply a with the mask and b with the inverted mask:

```
c = mask .* a + ~mask .* b
```